# Частая отправка http запроса

Tags: java, http, httpclient, http-post

Нужно отправлять http-запрос каждые 1000 мс.
В нормальном состоянии формирование, отправка и получение кода состояния занимает <1000мс.

То есть данные приходят как надо, например:

```
15:30:01,
15:30:02,
15:30:03,
15:30:04,
15:30:05.
```

Если пропадает связь, то неотправленные посылки нужно сохранить и передать позже.
Когда связи нет, то формирование, отправка и получение кода состояния иногда занимает >1500мс

И за счет этого записи сдвигаются

```
15:30:01,
15:30:03,
15:30:04,
15:30:06,
15:30:07.
```

Думаю и при ухудшении связи отправка может занять больше 1000мс.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как с этим бороться?

Comment: запускать в отдельных форках

Comment: Объединять неотправленные в один запрос

Comment: Объединяю записи в один запрос, тут загвоздка в том уходит сильно много времени с момента отправки и до вываливания исключения либо ответа сервера что что-то не так. Пробовал ставить таймаут меньше секунды с одной стороны вроде начинает быстрее работать с другой частые обрывы.

Comment: По поводу отдельных потоков нужно попробовать, может сработает

Comment: Обсуждения по настройке перфоманса обычно очень длинные, и комментарии для них не подходят. Предлагаю переместиться в чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35173/discussion-on-question-ru-488402 
а результат обсуждения уже перенести в ответы на исходный вопрос.